# setting id of tr while using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code for generating the table with angularjs dynamically which works fine:

```
<div  class="col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">

     <table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>item</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>number</th>
    <th>edit</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody ng-controller="table">
<tr  ng-repeat="x in typesHash ">
   <td>{{x.name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.price}}</td>
    <td>{{x.unit}}</td>
    <td>edit</td>
</tr>
  <tr>

  </tr>

</tbody>
```

and here is js code:

```
var app=angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('table',function($scope){
 $scope.typesHash=[
                 {name : 'lemon', price : 100,unit:2.5 },       
                 {name : 'meat', price : 200,unit:3.3  }];


   });
```

and here is the code fiddle link which works fine:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9av0edLd/1/)

now the problem is I want to assume id for tr as follow: id="tr"+x.name
for example : id="trlemon"
but I do not know how to set it. If I was producing this table with jquery I could easily do that but now with angularjs seems a little bit tricky can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the typical Angular expression `{{..}}`:

```
<tr id="tr{{x.name}}" ng-repeat="x in typesHash ">
</tr>
```